# How to make pages available to public while in pending status?

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page

I notice that pages with pending status become unavailable for viewing to the public. Is there a way to make sure the page is always available to the public? I would like the previous published version of the page should stay visible to public while it is still pending.

Anyone can advise?

I am running Sharepoint 2010 as a content management system for my company's website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To make pages available to public while in pending status, you can follow the steps below:

1. Fix the exception error status when occurring this exception.
2. Build a common page to deal this IIS Error Status which need to be deployed in correct SharePoint Directory.
3. Go to "internet information services manager" and click your Server node ".Net Error Pages".
4. Then add iis error dealing page setting which need your error status and your error page your can getted at step 1 and step 2.
5. At last in your define error dealing page (step 2), do the following:

1) look error source page by querying Request refter url OR querying source url  in querying url.

2) When find this page which you need dealing, then query current source page version number which can used.

3) Redirect to correct page，as example as followed

`http://localhost:8086/SitePages/Home.aspx` --> may redirect to --> `http://localhost:8086/SitePages/Home.aspx?PageVersion=1024`
1024 here is your correct page version.